# Mailboxer - All recipients except the originator of a conversation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mailboxer

Using Mailboxer I can find all participants in a conversation as

`@participants = @conversation.participants`

I can find the originator of a conversation using

`@originator = @conversation.originator`

Now I am trying to find all the participants except the originator.

`@participants.delete_if { |participant| participant == @originator}`

it is working fine but I wonder if there a better way of doing this? Thanks

Comment: you mean if there is a helper method in `MailBoxer` that directly getting participants without the originator?

Comment: @AhmedSamirShahin yes

Comment: Try `@participants = @conversation.recipients`

Comment: Did my answer helped you?

Comment: @Pavan it did, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the available helpers returns the *participants* without the *originator*. I expected [*recipients*](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mailboxer/mailboxer/Mailboxer/Conversation#recipients-instance_method) would help, but it does what [*participants*](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mailboxer/mailboxer/Mailboxer/Conversation#participants-instance_method) do.
Both the methods *returns all recipients with originator included*.

```
# File 'app/models/mailboxer/conversation.rb', line 78

def participants
  recipients
end

# File 'app/models/mailboxer/conversation.rb', line 72

def recipients
  return [] unless original_message
  Array original_message.recipients
end
```

You can use `reject` instead of `delete_if` but it is more or less the same. I recommend you to keep the *current approach* as it looks clean and better.